# Accessing the Youtube API using Meteor and percolate's google-api package

Tags: meteor, google-api, youtube-data-api

I've just started my first meteor project and I'm trying to access youtube's developer API.

I've created developer credentials with google, and I've included accounts-ui and percolate's google-api packages. I can successfully login with accounts-ui which means it appears my OAuth settings are working.

I then try to run something like this on the client:

```
GoogleApi.get('youtube/v3/search',{
    part : 'snippet',
    q : 'cats',
    maxResults : 25
  },
  function(err,data) {
    !err ? console.log(data) : console.log(err);
  });
```

And I get the following error on the console:

```
Error: failed [403] {  "error": {   "errors": [    {     "domain": "global",     "reason": "insufficientPermissions",     "message": "Insufficient Permission"    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Insufficient Permission"  } }
```

I'm not sure if I'm calling the function incorrectly, as I can't seem to find any usage examples of the GoogleApi.get() function (and I'm a meteor beginner), or whether my developer account is not properly setup, or what.

Any help or pointers you can pass along is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Update:
Using FullStack's suggestion below, my final code ended up looking like this:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";
        var params = {
            key: {Google API Key}
            part: "snippet",
            q: searchTerm,
            maxResults: 25
        };
        Meteor.http.get(url, {params: params}, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result.statusCode, result.data);
            var retdata = result.data;
            Session.set("youtubeSearchItems", retdata.items);
        });
```

Comment: What scopes is the user granting authorization for?

Comment: On my developer account, I've granted access to the youtube APIs for the project credentials I created. Not sure if this is what you mean?

Comment: @Watseka can you provide an example of the template and full js to call the search and display it to the client - I'm a meteor noob and am having a few issues with it. When I click my search button a 2nd, 3rd (etc) time the new results are appended to the container... Can you help me out with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend not using the google-api package and just doing the HTTP call yourself. Below is example code:

```
  var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search";
  var options = {
    'headers' : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + yourAccessToken,
      'X-JavaScript-User-Agent': "Google APIs Explorer"
    },
    'params' : {
       part : 'snippet',
       q : 'cats',
       maxResults : 25
    }
  };

  var searchResult = HTTP.get(url, options);
```

Make sure you have the HTTP package installed: `meteor add http`
See [official Meteor docs on HTTP](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http) for full details.

Answer (score 0):

Percolate's package works just fine. The issue is that you have `insufficient permissions` as it states. To fix this, you have to add the scopes that are necessary for the APIs you wish to use.

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
  ];
  Accounts.ui.config({
    requestPermissions: {google: scopes}
  });
}
```

I didn't know which YouTube API you were referring to so I went with the Data one. There's also Analytics and Live Streaming. I got the above scope from this page:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps